# PHP MySQL Cannot Insert Data from HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

I'm new at learning PHP.
I created a simple form that will accept customer information.
The problem here is that when I completely filled up the form and click submit, there is no data that has been inserted at the PhpMyAdmin.

At first I had used the normal procedure when INSERTING, at my 2nd attempt I used prepared statement method.

Here is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="column">
    <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px;">Order Form</p>



    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Customer</legend>
            <div style="text-align:right; float:right">
        <label for="txtorderdate">Order Date:</label><input type="date" name="orderdate" max="2017-12-18" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"><br></br>
        <label for="txtorderno">Order Number:</label><input type="number" name="orderno" align="right"><br></br>
        </div>
        <label for="txtcustname">Customer Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" required maxlength="50"><br></br>
        <label for="txtaddress">Address:</label><input type="text" name="address"><br></br>
        <label for="txtcontactname">Contact Name:</label><input type="text" name="cname"><br></br>
        <label for="txtphoneno">Phone:</label><input type="number" name="phone" maxlength="8" placeholder="999-9999">   <label for="txtmobileno">Mobile:</label><input type="number" name="mobile" maxlength="13" placeholder="9999-999-9999"><br></br>
        <label for="txtemailadd">E-mail Address:</label><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="user@email.com"><br></br>

        </fieldset>

        <div>
            <p style="margin-left: 20px;">Products to Order</p>
            <table border=2; style= margin:20px>
                <thead>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Quantity </th>
                        <th>Product Code</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Total Price</th>
                    </h3></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody align= "center" style= 'background-color: orange'>
                    <td>
                        <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:50px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center/><select name="" id="">
                        <option value='0'> </option>
                        <option value="">1</option>
                        <option value="">2</option>
                        <option value="">3</option>
                        <option value="">4</option>
                        <option value="">5</option>
                        <option value="">6</option>
                        <option value="">7</option>
                        <option value="">8</option>
                        <option value="">9</option>
                        <option value="">10</option></select></td>

                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text" style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:400px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>
                        <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:50px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center/><select name="" id="">
                        <option value='0'> </option>
                        <option value="">1</option> 
                        <option value="">2</option>
                        <option value="">3</option>
                        <option value="">4</option>
                        <option value="">5</option>
                        <option value="">6</option>
                        <option value="">7</option>
                        <option value="">8</option>
                        <option value="">9</option>
                        <option value="">10</option></select></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text" style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:400px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <td>
                        <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:50px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center/><select name="" id="">
                        <option value='0'> </option>
                        <option value="">1</option> 
                        <option value="">2</option>
                        <option value="">3</option>
                        <option value="">4</option>
                        <option value="">5</option>
                        <option value="">6</option>
                        <option value="">7</option>
                        <option value="">8</option>
                        <option value="">9</option>
                        <option value="">10</option></select></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text" style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:400px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <td>
                        <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:50px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center/><select name="" id="">
                        <option value='0'> </option>
                        <option value="">1</option> 
                        <option value="">2</option>
                        <option value="">3</option>
                        <option value="">4</option>
                        <option value="">5</option>
                        <option value="">6</option>
                        <option value="">7</option>
                        <option value="">8</option>
                        <option value="">9</option>
                        <option value="">10</option></select></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text" style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:400px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <td>
                        <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:50px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center/><select name="" id="">
                        <option value='0'> </option>
                        <option value="">1</option> 
                        <option value="">2</option>
                        <option value="">3</option>
                        <option value="">4</option>
                        <option value="">5</option>
                        <option value="">6</option>
                        <option value="">7</option>
                        <option value="">8</option>
                        <option value="">9</option>
                        <option value="">10</option></select></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text" style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input id="input" type="text"style="width:400px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><input style="width:100px"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <div>
        <p align ="right" style= margin:25px>Total: <input type = 'total' name = 'Total' disabled></p>
        <p style= margin:30px><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp<input type="reset" value="Reset"/></p>
        </div>
PHP

    <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    }
    else
    {

    }

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {   

            $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (`name`,`address`,`cname`,`phone`,`email`,`mobile`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);"
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['cname'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['mobile']);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
        }
        else
        {

        }

                mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: `var_dump()` something out under `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and see if you're making it that far.

Comment: @MCMXCII I tried to `var_dump()` something right after `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` but there's no output. It seems that I'm not getting there. I can't see what I am missing.

Comment: Please extract a minimal example and indicate where exactly it fails to behave as you would expect it to.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST) ` just above it and see what values you are getting